# FFMPEG Add 2 watermarks to an Image using single command

Tags: ffmpeg, watermark

How to add 2 watermarks to one image using ffmpeg. This is the command I am using for adding single watermark

```
ffmpeg -i actual-image.jpg -i watermark.png -filter_complex "overlay=5:5"  output.jpg
```

But i am not able to add 2 arguments for this. Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply 2 overlays. The 2nd overlay will use the result of the first overlay as its base input.

`ffmpeg -i actual-image.jpg -i watermark1.png -i watermark2.png -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=5:5[vid1];[vid1][2]overlay=300:300" output.jpg`